# Angular4 Print Handler

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4. HostListener does not seem to support window.onbeforeprint event handler. For chrome I was able to add a listener for window.matchMedia('print') outside of HostListener. However this does not work for IE and Firefox. What is the best way to work with window.onbeforeprint in angular 4.

```
@HostListener('window:onbeforeprint',['$event'])
onBeforePrint(event){
console.log('Before print');
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/4ZdLNklitwsucH0X6Azv

Answer (score 10):

try this

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:beforeprint',['$event'])
  onBeforePrint(event){
  console.log('Before print');
}
```

Instead of `onbeforeprint` use `beforeprint`